# How to list accessible templates from the CLI

Tags: templates, openshift

In OpenShift 3.9, I see many templates in the web console ("Add to project"). Those templates are provided by some central part of the company; i.e. they are not part of my OpenShift project (which I have full admin access to - but not to the OpenShift/Kubernetes cluster itself).

Is there a way to get the same list of template descriptions via `oc`? Specifically, I would like to use `oc process $INTERNALNAME`, but the tchnical name of the templates does not seem to be easily accessible to me through the GUI. In the past (OS 3.6), that would be easily accessible by inspecting the HTML of the GUI, but in 3.9 they seem to have switched that around, and I do not seem to be able to see those anymore (at least not easily - I can snoop network traffic in the browser, and check some internal AJAX request, but that's taking it a bit far for comfort...).

`oc get templates` does nothing, as the templates are external and not in my own project...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most templates are located in the namespace "openshift". The command below should give you these templates.

```
oc get templates -n openshift
```

alternatively you can query all templates:

```
oc get templates --all-namespaces
```

Comment: If you want to see both templates and images available, in both global ``openshift`` project and your own project, you can also use ``oc new-app -L``.